# Solve the IVP of the DE of form dy/dt=f(y/t)...

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following IVP:

$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{2y-3t}{3y-4t},\ \ \ \ y(1) = 2 $$

Here is my approach. I applied a substitution $ v = \frac{y}{t} $, which yields me the below:

$$ t\frac{dv}{dt} + v = \frac{2v-3}{3v-4} $$

I subtracted $v$ from both sides, and simplified, to get this seperable DE:

$$ \frac{dt}{t} = \frac{3v-4}{-3(v-1)^2} $$

This is the integral that I made, based off the initial value condition, with $s$ and $r$ as placeholder variables for $t$ and $v$ respectively:

$$ \int_{1}^{t} \frac{ds}{s} = \int_{2}^{v} \frac{3r-4}{-3(r-1)^2} dr $$

I can leave the answer implicitly. In the end, I substituted back y/t for v...

$$ t = exp\ \ (\int_{2/1}^{y/t} \frac{3(\frac{m}{n})-4}{-3(\frac{m}{n}-1)^2} \frac{dm}{dn}) $$

...where $m$ and $n$ are sort of placeholder variables. Is this approach (and answer) correct? I am allowed to leave my answer in implicit form. Thank you for helping out!

Comment: I would say solving the integral in $r$ may be your best choice. You can do it by expanding the fraction. Then, replace $v$ by $y/t$ and you are good.

Comment: @Snifkes Thank you, so I can do the partial fraction stuff. I do have one question...would my final answer up there be good enough?

Comment: I checked you process until the integration in $r$ and it seems well done. What you can do is: once you solve for the implicit relation of $y$ and $t$ derive the whole expression in $t$ and use the expression of $dy/dt$ to see if you get an agreement.

Comment: @Snifkes Alright, thank you!

Comment: I think there may be a typo in the final answer? You have an integral with $\frac{dm}{dn}$ at the end... Also, by leaving the answer in implicit form, I don't think they mean to leave it as an integral. I think Dr. Sonnhard Graubner's answer gives you a solution which is in the implicit form they want.

Comment: @JohnDoe I substituted $dr$ for $\frac{dm}{dn}$, because I wanted to put the equation back in terms of $\frac{y}{t}$ rather than v. Is this not acceptable? EDIT: Never mind, I will just go with Dr. Graubner's answer. Thank you!

Comment: It is worth pointing out where you have made a slight mistake: you don't actually need to change the integration variables. After all, $v$ actually _equals_ $y/t$ by definition. So $$\int_{2}^{y/t} \frac{3r-4}{-3(r-1)^2} dr$$is correct, and that would be fine. That being said, you should evaluate the integral (as shown in the answer). By the way, if you did want to do the substitution of $m/n$, then it would become something like $dr=d\left(\frac mn\right)=\frac1n\,dm$. They key point being, only one $d$. But as shown above, there's no point in doing this - keep the $r$.

Answer (score 1):

Substituting $$y(t)=v(t)t$$ we get
$$t\frac{dv(t)}{dt}+v(t)=\frac{-3t+2tv(t)}{-4t+3tv(t)}$$ and this is
$$\frac{\frac{dv(t)}{dt}(3v(t)-4)}{(v(t)-1)^2}=-\frac{3}{t}$$ and now integrate!
This gives $$-3\log(v(t)-1)+\frac{1}{v(t)-1}=-3\log(t)+C_1$$

Comment: (+1) Yes, i think this is what they mean by leaving the answer in implicit form

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{2y-3t}{3y-4t},\ \ \ \ y(1) = 2$$

$$ (2y-3t)dt+(-3y+4t)dy=0$$

Use the integrating factor 
$$\mu (t,y)= \frac 1 {(t-y)^2}$$
Then the differential equation is exact and you can easily get an implicit form...
$$
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle
f(t,y)= \int \frac {2y-3t}{(t-y)^2} dt+\phi(y) \\
\displaystyle
f(t,y)= \int \frac {4t-3y}{(t-y)^2} dy+\psi(t) 
\end{cases}
$$
$$ \implies 3 \ln|t-y|+ \frac t {y-t}=K \,\,\,;\, y(1)=2 \implies K=1$$
$$\boxed { 3 \ln|t-y|+ \frac t {y-t}=1}$$